# Identifying previous items using xpath in Selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I want to check the checkbox based on the value in the text input labeled 'Field' I have tried the following:

```
<tr>
    <td>check</td>
    <td>/label[text()="Field"]/../input[@value="6 1012 49817"]/preceding-sibling::label[text()="Private"]/../input</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="wdg colShwHdeCls" id="divFormFieldPrivate-0" style="width: 82px;">
<input id="FormFieldPrivate-0" name="FormFieldPrivate-0" title="" style="" class="wdg colShwHdeCls" type="checkbox">
<label for="FormFieldPrivate-0">Private</label>
</div>
<div class="csLineBreak"> </div>
<div class="acI fldWd100 wdg colShwHdeOpn" id="divFormFieldId-0"><label for="FormFieldId-0">Field<a class="aut" title="Show selection list"></a>
<a style="display: inline-block; opacity: 0.0118143;" href="field/view?FieldId=" title="View this Field" class="acOptVw acLb acI"></a>
<a style="display: inline-block; opacity: 0.0118143;" href="field/edit?FieldId=" class="acEd acLb acI" title="Edit this Field"></a>
<a style="display: inline-block; opacity: 0.0118143;" href="field/add?FieldId=" class="acAd lightbox acI" title="Add a new Field"></a>
</label>
<br>
<span style="display:none;" id="FormFieldId-0-Old">6 1012 49817</span>
<input id="FormFieldId-0" name="FormFieldId-0" value="11955" type="hidden">
<input autocomplete="off" id="FormFieldId-0-Dsp" title="type three or more characters to see selection list" class="wdg csAutCpl csAutCplFld ui-autocomplete-input" value="6 1012 49817" type="text">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" aria-live="polite" role="status"></span>
</div>
```

Suggestions are welcome thanks ;-)

Comment: You ONLY want to check the check box if the value in the input field (FormFieldId-0-Dsp) if the value matches a preselected value?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have it working, and in other cases too - a tutorial in preceding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way. First part of the XPath supposed to find the `div` element containing `label` with certain text (`"Field"` in this case) and `input` with certain `value` attribute :

```
//div[label[normalize-space(text())="Field"] and input[@value="6 1012 49817"]]
```

From the above `div`, find preceding sibling `div` containing `label` with text equals `"Private"`, then get the `input` child element of that `div` :

```
/preceding-sibling::div[label[text()="Private"]]/input
```

So the entire XPath will look about like this :

```
//div[label[normalize-space(text())="Field"] and input[@value="6 1012 49817"]]/preceding-sibling::div[label[text()="Private"]]/input
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester.com demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/efaa22cc61dcb5f75e7ad26138f87d52)</kbd>**

Comment: Excellent, thanks @har07, your help is most appreciated. +1 for the succinct and yet detailed reply ;-)